# BigBlueButton 2-3-dev html5client showing “404 not found”

Tags: bigbluebutton

I'm having the same issue after upgrading to 2.3 on Ubuntu 18. Everything loads, bbb-conf --status all active, no errors on bbb but I keep getting the "404 Not found" error when trying to access the Redlight Rooms or any resource requiring the html5 client application.

After running sudo bbb-conf --debug I get some errors as shown below:

May 25 21:37:11 cloudroom sh[28344]: SignalException: SIGTERM May 25 21:37:14 cloudroom sh[28344]: Original Exception (Redis::CannotConnectError): Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) May 25 21:37:14 cloudroom sh[28344]: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in standard_exception_handling' May 25 21:45:37 cloudroom sh[29476]: SignalException: SIGTERM May 25 21:45:41 cloudroom sh[29476]: Original Exception (Redis::CannotConnectError): Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) May 25 21:45:41 cloudroom sh[29476]: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in standard_exception_handling' May 25 22:03:58 cloudroom sh[4189]: SignalException: SIGTERM May 25 22:04:02 cloudroom sh[4189]: Original Exception (Redis::CannotConnectError): Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) May 25 22:04:02 cloudroom sh[4189]: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in standard_exception_handling' May 25 22:30:07 cloudroom sh[6716]: SignalException: SIGTERM May 25 22:30:08 cloudroom run-prod.sh[6823]: 2021-05-25T22:30:08.231Z WARN  i.l.c.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog - Cannot reconnect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379 May 25 22:30:08 cloudroom run-prod.sh[6823]: 2021-05-25T22:30:08.235Z WARN  i.l.c.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog - Cannot reconnect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379 May 25 22:30:08 cloudroom run-prod.sh[6823]: 2021-05-25T22:30:08.256Z WARN  i.l.c.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog - Cannot reconnect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379 May 25 22:30:08 cloudroom run-prod.sh[6823]: 2021-05-25T22:30:08.257Z WARN  i.l.c.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog - Cannot reconnect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379 May 25 22:30:11 cloudroom sh[6716]: Original Exception (Redis::CannotConnectError): Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) May 25 22:30:11 cloudroom sh[6716]: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:186:in standard_exception_handling'

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to solce this for the past two days.

Comment: you probably need to supply more info to get help with this, try formatting your stack-traces see Daniel Fischer answer here for possible format example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141336/correct-way-to-format-errors-messages-or-stacktraces/141345

Comment: you could provide information about your deployment like are you using the docker stack?  then the redis logs and  redis service status( is running?) and also check   6379 is open to get started, generally well formatted questions with relevant supporting info get the most attention